# HTTP(S) vs TCP/UDP requests

Tags: http, сеть, tcp, gcp

Готовлюсь к сдаче GCP и увидел, что в этих клаудах лоуд балансеры делятся на типы: HTTP(S) Load balancer, TCP Proxy, SSL Proxy, TCP Load Balancer (without SSL offload).

Не могу понять, HTTP(S) работает же поверх TCP. Почему тогда запросы могут разделяться на HTTP и TCP запросы, если это протоколы разных уровней, один с которых зависим от другого. 
Каким вообще может быть TCP запрос (любой пример кроме SMTP)? Для каких задач это может использоваться?

Что-то совсем запутало меня это все.

Comment: Да, НТТР протокол базируется на TCP, на базе TCP есть много других протоколов. 1)Все виды прокси (если не ошибаюсь) идут через TCP, так же много протоколов базируются на ТСP. 2)Появился web-овский "сокет" для чатов, и другие "експерементальные" протоколы...

Comment: Все зависит от того, по какому принципу решено сделать балансировку. Самое простое - отдаем новое соединение одному случайному серверу. Но от одного клиента может быть много подключений и когда они на разных серверах начинаются проблемы обмена данными между серверами. Решение в лоб - по ip пользователя, в принципе работоспособно, если у него ip не часто меняется. Это все реализуемо на уровне TCP...

Comment: Если же вы хотите одного и того же пользователя всегда бросать на один сервер (что бы другим серверам не надо было знать о нем все) и ip не достаточно, то появляются другие механизмы, например по куке в http. И вот тут уже необходимо что бы балансер понимал http, что бы достать из него куку ...

Comment: @nick_n_a, `НТТР протокол базируется на TCP` - на UDP тоже может, хотя [редко](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp)